# A conjecture with connection to the $abc$-conjecture

Tags: number-theory, radicals, conjectures, abc-conjecture

The numbers $\,a,b,c\,$ is a $abc$-triplet if they are coprime and $a+b=c$. One version of the abc-conjecture is then:

> For all $\varepsilon>0$ the set $E_\varepsilon$ of all $abc$-triplets with 
>   $c>\text{rad}(a\cdot b\cdot c)^{1+\varepsilon}$ is finite.
>   where $\,\text{rad}(p_1^{n1}\cdots p_k^{n_k})=p_1\cdots p_k$ and $\,p_1,\dots ,p_k$ are arbitrary primes.

But it is known that $E_0$ is infinite. Conjecture:

> For $abc$-triplets,
>   $(a,b,c),(a',b',c')\in E_0\,$ and 
>   $\,a^2+b^2=a'^2+b'^2\implies \{a,b\}=\{a',b'\}$

So far tested for all $a,b$ less than $10^5$. Can this be proved?

[image]

Diagram for the 9 exceptional abc-triplets with least distance to origo:
$(1,8),(5,27),(1,48),(32,49),(1,63),(1,80),(4,121),(3,125),(81,175)$

http://forthmath.blogspot.se/2016/08/the-abc-conjecture-1.html

Comment: As detailled in wikipedia :*for a positive integer $n$, the radical of $n$, denoted $rad(n)$, is the product of the distinct prime factors of $n$. For example $rad(16) = rad(2^4) = 2$ , $rad(17) = 17$,    $rad(18) = rad(2 ⋅ 3^2) = 2 · 3 = 6$,* etc

Comment: I checked the conjecture up to $a,b\le300$, and it holds. Now if I only understood how to make my naive python script more efficient...

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: I use Pollard Rho to factorize and calculate the radical and it's rather fast. But looking over my routine http://forthmath.blogspot.se/2016/08/the-abc-conjecture-1.html I see there is a lot to be done to optimize.

Comment: @Lehs I'll take a look at that. My simplistic radical computation took up something like 99.99% of the total running time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list of triples $(A,B,C)$ (for $C<10^{18}$) such that $$A+B=C,\\rad(ABC)<C,\tag{1}$$
is accessible by the link [Bart de Smit/ABC triples/by size][1], file [abctriples_below_1018.gz][2] .

A quick check yields that your statement is true for ABC-triples with $C< 10^{18}$.