# Conjecture: injection from exceptional abc-triplets to natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, radicals, conjectures, abc-conjecture

> My question
>   [A conjecture with connection to the $abc$-conjecture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904616/a-conjecture-with-connection-to-the-abc-conjecture)
>   is about a conjectured injection from exceptional
>   $abc$-triplets $(a,b,c)\mapsto a^2+b^2$, but this question is about a conjectured injection from exceptional $abc$-triplets $(a,b,c)\mapsto a+2b$. It's similar
>   but not a duplicate.

---

The numbers $\,a,b,c\,$ is a $abc$-triplet if they are coprime and $a+b=c$. One version of the abc-conjecture is then:

> For all $\varepsilon>0$ the set $E_\varepsilon$ of all $abc$-triplets with 
>   $c>\text{rad}(a\cdot b\cdot c)^{1+\varepsilon}$ is finite.
>   where $\,\text{rad}(p_1^{n1}\cdots p_k^{n_k})=p_1\cdots p_k$ and $\,p_1,\dots ,p_k$ are arbitrary primes.

But it is known that $E_0$ is infinite. Conjecture:

> For $abc$-triplets, where $a<b$,
>   $(a,b,c),(a',b',c')\in E_0\,$ and 
>   $\,a+2b=a'+2b'\implies \{a,b\}=\{a',b'\}$

So far tested for all $a,b$ less than $100,000$. Can this be proved?

### [image]

There is no uniqueness for $a+b$, $a-b$ or $2a+b$.

---

Comment: See also for [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904616/a-conjecture-with-connection-to-the-abc-conjecture) related question.

Comment: Given that those other simple linear polynomials don't result in an injective map, why do you think this one does?

Comment: Are you further assuming $a<b$, so (a,b,c) and (b,a,c) are not both $abc$-triplets? I suppose you must be to be considering $2a+b$ and $a+2b$ separately.

Comment: @Zander what is $\{a,b\}$ ?

Comment: $(a,b,c)=(1,386560,386561)$, $(a',b',c')=(4913,384104,389017)$, $a+2b=a'+2b'=773121$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conjecture is not true. For a counterexample consider
$$
(a,b,c) = (1,386560,386561)
\quad (a',b',c') = (4913,384104,389017)
$$
which are $abc$-triplets with $a<b$, $a'<b'$, $a+2b=a'+2b'$ and $\{a,b\}\neq\{a',b'\}$.